# How to get 5 years before now

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to java 8 and I am trying to get five years before now, here is my code:

```
Instant fiveYearsBefore = Instant.now().plus(-5,
                    ChronoUnit.YEARS);
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Years
```

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Try to specify more precisely what you mean by 5 years ago. A year is not a constant unit of duration. Some years are a bit longer than other years. Do you want the same date as today, 5 years ago? Or do you want 5*365 days ago?

Comment: Invoke `new FlyingDelorean().Builder.speed(88).unit(Unit.MILES_PER_HOUR).build();`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907925/why-instant-does-not-support-operations-with-chronounit-years

Comment: Time math ain't easy. Imagine instant corresponds to 13:00 Feb 29, 2012. What should instant.plus(-1, ChronoUnit.YEARS) return? Whatever you think it should return, now think what instant.plus(-1, ChronoUnit.YEARS).plus(1, ChronoUnit.YEARS) return.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
ZonedDateTime.now().minusYears(5).toInstant()
```

That will use your default time zone to compute the time. If you want another one, specify it in `now()`. For example:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusYears(5).toInstant()
```

Answer (score 16):

According to the Javadoc, Instant will only accept temporal units from nanos to days [Instant.plus(long amountToAdd, TemporalUnit unit);](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

You can use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). You use it the same way, but it will support operation on the YEARS level.

Comment: Thanks for stating what TemporalUnits are supported

Answer (score 9):

Instant does not support addition or subtraction of YEARS.

You can use this LocalDate if you only need date without time:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
date = date.plus(-5, ChronoUnit.YEARS);
```

Otherwise you can user LocalDateTime.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. `Instant` does NOT support years - and that is why the OP has a problem.

Comment: Thnx! It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same exception, but with ChronoUnit.MONTHS. It is a little bit misleading, because on compile time does not throw an error or warning or something.
Anyway, I read the documentation, too: [image]

and, yes, all the other ChronoUnit types are not supported unfortunately.

Happily, LocalDateTime can substract months and years, too.

> LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(yearsBack)

> LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(monthsBack);

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```java
LocalDate                            // Represent a date only, no time, no zone.
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" )  // Today's date varies by zone.
)
.minusYears( 5 )                     // Go back in time by years.
.toString()                          // Generate text is standard format.
```

Run code [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/lIkLCg).

> 2018-11-20

For your copy-paste convenience:

```
LocalDate.now().minusYears( 5 )  // Using JVM’s current default time zone to get today's date.
```

### `LocalDate`

If you want simply the date, without time-of-day, and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). To move back in years, call [`minusYears`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusYears(long)).

### `ZoneId`

To capture the current date, specify [a time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Understand that for any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. It's "tomorrow" in `Asia/Tokyo` while still "yesterday" in `America/Edmonton`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate fiveYearsAgo = today.minusYears( 5 ) ;
```

FYI, see list of [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) names, with `Continent/Region` names.

### Generate text

Generate text is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = fiveYearsAgo.toString() ;
```

Answer (score -6):

If you are so inclined is does not require the date time conversion.

```
Instant.now().minus(Period.ofYears(5).getDays(),ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Comment: Does not work! Java is so disappointing! Does not even do what it says! `Period.ofYears(5).getDays()` value is 0

Comment: Actually `getDays()` does exactly what it says. Look at the JavaDoc:
_The resulting period will have the specified months. The years and days units will be zero._

Comment: This worked for me: `Instant.now().minus(5 * 365L, ChronoUnit.DAYS)`

Comment: You can't know how many days there are in five years with `Period.ofYears(5).getDays()`. It's a question that doesn't make any sense because you haven't specified _which_ years. It might be a leap year, it might not. The days count would vary.